# EF репозиторий update many-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

Привет!

Юзаю ef code first + всё обёрнуто в репозиторий. Допустим, у меня есть такие модели:

```
class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    // other things
}

class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }    
}
```

В Article репозитории:

```
public IQueryable<Article> Articles
{
  get { return Db.Articles; }
}

public bool UpdateArticle(Article instance)
{
  Article cache = Db.Articles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == instance.Id);

  if (cache != null)
  {
    cache.Content = instance.Content;
    cache.Title = instance.Title;
    //...

    // собственно, вопрос.
    // Как мне обновлять теги? Может быть и удаление и добавление
    // Нужно найти все новые, удалить старые, отсеять неизменившиеся и т. д.
    // Но это несколько расточительство - что, если изменился только один тег?
    //
    // Тогда использовал что-то подобное урезанное, без удаления. 
    // Удаление делал напрямую в модели, т. е. Articles.First(..).Tags.Remove(..)
    foreach (Tag tag in instance.Tags.Except(cache.Tags, TagEqualityComparer.Get))
    {
      cache.Tags.Add(tag);
    }

    Db.Entry(cache).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Db.SaveChanges();

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Пример из давнего проекта, но сейчас такая же проблема +модель приходит из wcf-сервиса, т. е. доступа к DbContext не имею, т. е. просто переложить проблему на ef не получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите примеры работы модели [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/5.10.php)  и [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/5.11.php)
По большому счету все делается также, как и при обычном редактировании модели, только в данном случае вы редактируете не ординарное свойство, а свойство, содержащее коллекцию.

Comment: Ну как и думал. Накладно немного. Спасиб!

Пока не закрываю вопрос, может кто добавит ещё чего.